# Error running lostash codec plugin

Tags: logstash

i've generated a codec plugin using the logstash-plugin generate and installed it. when i try to run, i end up with the following error:

> d:\Downloads\logstash-5.1.1>bin\logstash -f
>   ..\logstash-avro\config.cfg JAVA_OPTS was set to [ -Xmx1g
>   -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8  -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutO fMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="d:\Downloads/heapdump.hprof"]. Logstash will trust these options, and not set any default s that it might usually set
>   14:27:12.324 [LogStash::Runner] INFO  logstash.codecs.avrotest - Using
>   version 0.1.x codec plugin 'avrotest'. This plugi n isn't well
>   supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. 14:27:12.338
>   [LogStash::Runner] ERROR logstash.agent - fetched an invalid config
>   {:config=>"input { \n  stdin{ codec => avrotest{}} \n} \noutput {\n 
>   stdout { codec => rubydebug }\n}\n\n", :reason=>"uninitialized
>   constant LogStash::Codecs:: Line"}

Do i need to reference or initalize something, so that i can use the Line plugin inside the codec plugin?

thanks,

Helmut

Comment: If you could show your logstash file?

Comment: It is only a test running from stdin, like it is described in writing a codec plugin:
input { 
  stdin{ codec => avrotest{}} 
} 
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your `codec => avrotest{}`. What's avortest by the way ?

Comment: avrotest is the name of my codec pluin, which i created based using the documentation on how to write a codec plugin. it is like the example plugin, just the name is different.

Comment: you're using the same command as [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_codec_plugin.html#_test_installation_2) to run the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the exception, it seems like you're missing out something in your logstash configuration.
I haven't tried out `avro` plugin personally, but from what I saw shouldn't your `input` look like this:

```
input { 
    stdin{ 
        codec => avrotest{}
    }
}
```

[Ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-avro.html)

Comment: That gives me an error. i was following the guide described here: [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_codec_plugin.html)

at the very end they show the parameters to run it.

Comment: You are right i need to have the config file, like you showed.
thanks for pointing that out.

[Documentation ](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_codec_plugin.html) is then wrong

Comment: Yes, it worked. i have now another problem, but this is not related to the above